# Handling ajax post data in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework, zend-framework2

So i've got some information I send with a Post ajax request like this:

```
$.ajax("<?php echo $this->url('panel/academy/locals/editlocal')?>", {
                method: 'POST',
                data: {
                    id: id, // number
                    distrito: newDistrito, // string
                    direccion: newDireccion, // string
                    telefono1: newTelf1, // string
                    telefono2: newTelf2, // string
                        efectivo: $('#local_'+id).find('.efectivo').prop('checked'),
                        visa: $('#local_'+id).find('.visa').prop('checked'),
                        mastercard: $('#local_'+id).find('.mastercard').prop('checked'),
                        american: $('#local_'+id).find('.american').prop('checked'),
                        deposito: $('#local_'+id).find('.deposito').prop('checked'),
                    central: newCentral,
                }
            })
```

efectivo, visa, american, mastercard and central are all booleans.

In the server I do this:

```
$prg = $this->prg();
    if($prg instanceof \Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response)
        return $prg;
    elseif ($prg === false)
        return new JsonModel(array(
            'msg' =>'error prg false',
            'success' => false
        ));

    $localForm = new LocalForm();
    $localForm->setData($prg);

    if(!$localForm->isValid()){
        return new JsonModel(array(
            'success ' => false,
            'error' => 'Invalid',
        ));
    }

    $id = (int) $localForm->get('id')->getValue();

    $local = (new LocalMapper())->byId($id);

    //change local model
    $local->setDistrictId($localForm->get('distrito')->getValue());
    $local->setAddress($localForm->get('direccion')->getValue());
    $local->setPhone1($localForm->get('telefono1')->getValue());
    $local->setPhone2($localForm->get('telefono2')->getValue());
    $local->setCentral($localForm->get('central')->getValue());

    $localpayments = (new LocalPaymentMapper())->byLocalId($id);

    // I will have to fix what I'm about to do as soon as possible
    foreach($localpayments as $payment){
        // Efectivo 1
        // Visa 2
        // Mastercard 3
        // American Express 4
        switch($payment->getPaymentId()){
            case 1:
                if(!$prg['efectivo']){
                    $payment->delete();
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                if(!$prg['visa']){
                    $payment->delete();
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                if(!$prg['mastercard']){
                    $payment->delete();
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                if(!$prg['american']){
                    $payment->delete();
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

the problem is that when i try to add an element to the localForm that holds a boolean value like a checkbox the form is always invalid and so I never get to the part where I acccess the db and save the changes the user made. I tried using the $prg array to acces the info but had no luck either. How can I acomplish this? am I trying the wrong approach?

Thanks in advance

here is the full form

```
<?php

namespace GrouPanel\Form\Locals;

use GrouCore\Form\Form;
use GrouCore\Form\Element\DistrictSelector;
use GrouCore\Form\Element\UserPhone;
use GrouCore\Form\Element\LocalAddress;
use Zend\Form\Element\Checkbox;

class LocalForm extends Form {
    public function __construct($name = "localForm") {
    parent::__construct ( $name );
    $this->setAttribute ( 'novalidate', 'novalidate' );

    $localDistrict = new DistrictSelector ( 'distrito' );
    $localAddress = new LocalAddress ( 'direccion' );
    $localPhone1 = new UserPhone ( 'telefono1' );
    $localPhone2 = new UserPhone ( 'telefono2' );
    $localCentral = new Checkbox ( 'central' );

    $this->add ( array (
            'name' => 'id',
            'type' => 'text'
    ) );
    $this->add( $localDistrict )
        ->add( $localAddress )
        ->add ( $localPhone1 )
        ->add ( $localPhone2 )
        ->add ( $localCentral );
    $this->getInputFilter ();
}
```

DistrictSelector, UserPhone and LocalAddress all work as expected, the checkbox seems to be the problem somehow

Comment: Could you share what type of validation you have with your LocalForm and also does your checkbox have a value specified?

Comment: @xangxiong added the form

Comment: So since you are using Zend\Form\Element\CheckBox, I  believe it looks for 1 when the checkbox is checked and 0  for unchecked.  In your HTML definition for your checkbox,  is the value set to 1? Or instead of sending a boolean over POST, send 0/1 instead.

Answer (score 0):

You use the syntax jQuery.ajax( url [, settings ] ). Try adding key :

```
dataType: 'json',
```

in your setting structure.

Answer (score 0):

Http stringified every thing before send.
so you can use 1 or 0 instead of true or false in js.

```
efectivo: ($('#local_'+id).find('.efectivo').prop('checked')) ? 1 : 0,
```

add to ajax

```
dataType: 'json',
```